# vbscript to split very large text files

Tags: vbscript

I'm new to vbscript and I'm having trouble with something that should be relatively easy.  I have two very large text files that I have to split into many different text files based on certain lines in the files.  Here is a sample of the text file:

```
F1 SA1056-540X0
F21 All_Tools
F3 123229 99819 30MIL
F3 317229 99819 30MIL
F5 0 0
F51 0 0
F6 136103 204045
F7 0 0
F8 265094 249728 90000 1 N N 455229
F9 C1A
F8 265094 208328 90000 1 N N 455229
F9 C1B
F12 0.125000 250 0
F1 SA1056-550X1
F21 All_Tools
F3 123229 99819 30MIL
F3 317229 99819 30MIL
F5 0 0
F51 0 0
F6 136103 204045
F7 0 0
F8 265094 249728 90000 1 N N 455229
F9 C1A
F8 265094 208328 90000 1 N N 455229
F9 C1B
F12 0.125000 250 0
```

The F1 line will provide the name of the new text file while the F12 line will be the last line in that new text file.  The next F1 will be the next file and so on.  Here is my code.  Does the ReadLine method not advance to the next line?

```
Dim fso, newFile, folderPath

folderPath = "C:\MyDataTest"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

For Each file In fso.GetFolder(folderPath).Files

    Do While Not file.OpenAsTextStream.AtEndOfStream
        strLine = file.OpenAsTextStream.ReadLine
        strChar = file.OpenAsTextStream.Read(3)
        Do While strChar <> "F12"
            If strChar = "F1 " Then
                fileName = Replace(strLine, "F1 ", "")
                newFilePath = folderPath + "\" + fileName + ".txt"
                Set newFile = fso.CreateTextFile(newFilePath, True)
                newFile.WriteLine(strLine)
                strLine = file.OpenAsTextStream.ReadLine
                strChar = file.OpenAsTextStream.Read(3)
            Else
                newFile.WriteLine(strLine)
                strLine = file.OpenAsTextStream.ReadLine
                strChar = file.OpenAsTextStream.Read(3)
            End If
        Loop
        newFile.WriteLine(strLine)
        newFile.Close
    loop

Next
```

This creates the file and writes the first F1 line and then I get a Permission denied runtime error on the "Set newFile = fso.CreateTextFile(newFilePath, True)" line.  I'm sure that I'm missing a much easier way of doing this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure it out.  Here is the code for any who are interested:

```
Dim fso, fs, newFile, folderPath

folderPath = "C:\MyDataTest"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")


For Each file In fso.GetFolder(folderPath).Files
    Set fileSplit = fso.OpenTextFile(file)
    Do While Not fileSplit.AtEndOfStream
        strLine = fileSplit.ReadLine
        testStr = Left(strLine, 3)
        If Left(strLine, 3) <> "F12" Then
            If Left(strLine, 3) = "F1 " Then
                fileName = Replace(strLine, "F1 ", "")
                newFilePath = (folderPath + "\" + fileName + ".txt")
                Set newFile = fs.CreateTextFile(newFilePath, True)
                newFile.WriteLine(strLine)
            Else
                newFile.WriteLine(strLine)
            End If
        Else
            newFile.WriteLine(strLine)
            newFile.Close
        End If

    loop
    fileSplit.Close
Next
```